# How do I use Hashicorp's Linux Repository with Centos 8 and cloud-init to install Vault

Tags: centos, repository, cloud-init

How do I use [Hashicorp's Linux Repository](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/announcing-the-hashicorp-linux-repository) with Centos 8 and cloud-init to install `vault`?

I have tried this cloud-config file without success:

```yml
#cloud-config

package_update: true
packages:
  - jq
  - vault
yum_repos:
  hashicorp:
    name: Hashicorp Stable
    baseurl: https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo
    enabled: true
    gpgcheck: true
    gpgkey: https://rpm.reelases.hashicorp.com/gpg
```

The error that I get from `cloud-init` did't lead me to assistance online:

```
[   57.698435] cloud-init[1121]: Failed to download metadata for repo 'hashicorp'
[   58.595136] cloud-init[1121]: Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'hashicorp'
[   58.623309] cloud-init[1121]: Cloud-init v. 18.5 running 'modules:config' at Thu, 29 Oct 2020 19:26:01 +0000. Up 43.25 seconds.
[   58.633274] cloud-init[1121]: 2020-10-29 19:26:16,555 - util.py[WARNING]: Package update failed
[   61.096376] cloud-init[1121]: Hashicorp Stable                                6.1 kB/s | 376  B     00:00
[   61.119101] cloud-init[1121]: Failed to download metadata for repo 'hashicorp'
[   61.125684] cloud-init[1121]: Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'hashicorp'
```

I expect to be able to refer to Hashicorp's repository like other repositories; such as the following, which works to install SaltStack's `salt-master`:

```yml
#cloud-config

package_update: true
packages:
  - salt-master
  - jq
yum_repos:
  saltstack-repo:
    name: SaltStack repo for RHEL/CentOS 8 PY3
    baseurl: https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/redhat/8/$basearch/archive/3001.1
    enabled: true
    gpgcheck: true
    gpgkey: https://repo.saltstack.com/py3/redhat/8/$basearch/archive/3001.1/SALTSTACK-GPG-KEY.pub
```

My current workaround is to install in a shell script which I configure to run once:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit

# Install vault from Hashicorp's official repo.
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo
yum install -y vault
```

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL `https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/hashicorp.repo` is not the repository URL, but the YUM configuration file for the repository.  The `yum-config-manager` command works with YUM configuration files, so that is working fine.

The URL you want to use can be found within that file: `baseurl=https://rpm.releases.hashicorp.com/RHEL/$releasever/$basearch/stable`.

Answer (score 0):

hey this is old but i came across this issue while trying to add the hashicorp repo to kali. i haven't found any current solutions that worked except when i altered this command that i found on a different board. copy pasting the command below will add the repo to Kali Linux:

`echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/hashicorp-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com bullseye main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hashicorp.list`

the part you want to edit is where it says bullseye. modify that to your distribution of centos and it should probably work?

Comment: "i haven't found any current solutions that worked" - That's because [as per Kali developers](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/) _"adding other operating system’s repositories into Kali (such as trying to put Ubuntu on Kali), will break your installation. This is the single most common reason why Kali Linux systems break.

If any guides are telling you to do anything else than the above, this is unofficial advice, and completely not supported by Kali Linux. More often than not, users in this case end up doing a reinstall after learning this lesson."_

Comment: oh yeah, my bad. what this guy said. anywaysm if you're running vms or don't care about your rig, i'm still running fine

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't as much intended for you as for the future generations who stumble upon this trying to figure out why their Kali went haywire after they installed CoD from Steam repo :-)